# OpenCV imshow() function shows a single colored window instead of an image

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I've been trying to just take a picture with OpenCV but imshow() returns a single colored image instead.
It doesn't return any Error.

```
import cv2
from time import sleep

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

ret, frame = camera.read()
sleep(1)
cv2.imshow("frame", frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imwrite("image.jpg", frame)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[Here is the window created while running this code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzSDX.png)

My cam is fully working with other programs and python programs, but i can't make this work.
I've tried changing the camera port, rerun pycharm and even restart my computer and cam, but didn't work as well.
When i try to save the image with imwrite() it doesn't work either.

[image saved with imwrite()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt8yY.png)

Help?

EDIT:
It probably was my camera, because i made a program that takes pictures every 5 seconds, and after the second picture, it worked normally.

Comment: You could help yourself by saying which camera you are using. And which OS. And printing the shape and dtype of the image you acquire. And the return value. And the min/max and mean of the image channels. And checking the available modes. And actually specifying one of the modes/resolutions.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre].

Comment: did you seriously *take a screenshot* of the saved image file?